# Creating a Wise Ordering of Writes cache on Windows

Tags: windows, algorithm, winapi, caching, disk-io

I'm considering creating a [wise ordering of writes cache](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=v0_0U4HXEsiw0AXv0YDwDw&url=https://www.usenix.org/event/fast05/tech/full_papers/gill/gill.pdf&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNG7i16FaDxtIRa0anmkaD4GfGbg5w) (WOW cache) for a database system I'm building, but I'm having trouble mapping regions of the file to physical disk regions.

I've discovered you can use [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the virtual cluster allocations for a file but I'm unsure how to relate this to physical disk locations.

Is this possible on Windows? If not is there a workaround or a more applicable write caching algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

1. First, open the handle to a volume using `CreateFile` routine (use `\\?\C:` as the name of volume **C:**).
2. Use `DeviceIoControl` with `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` to retrieve the physical location of a volume on one or more disks.

Thus, you will have the physical location of a volume within a disk (or several disk in more complex setups) and the virtual cluster allocation for a file within a volume. Combine these two pieces of information to get physical location of a file within a disk.

P.S. Possibly, you may also need some auxiliary information as the size of the disk sector and the size of the volume cluster.